# Calculate not-nulls in group by

Tags: oracle, group-by, aggregate, null

I have a `TRAILS` table:

```
+----+------------+-----------------+
| ID |  LENGTH    | CONDITION (1-5) |
+----+------------+-----------------+
|  1 |    23.1    | null            |
|  2 |    41.7    | 1               |
|  3 |    10.9    | 4               |
|  4 |     6.2    | null            |
|  5 |    70.6    | 2               |
|  6 |    82.1    | 2               |
+----+------------+-----------------+
```

I want to summarize the table like this:

```
     +------------+-----------------+----------------------------+
     | TOT_LENGTH |  AVG_CONDITION  | CONDITION_PERCENT_COMPLETE |
     +------------+-----------------+----------------------------+
     |      234.6 |            2.25 |                        66% |
     +------------+-----------------+----------------------------+
```

I can do a `GROUP BY` to get the `TOT_LENGTH` and `AVG_CONDITION`, but I'
m not sure how to get the `CONDITION_PERCENT_COMPLETE`, without eliminating `NULLS` from the query/other columns.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`COUNT(condition)` counts all rows in the group where `condition` is not null.

`COUNT(*)` counts all rows in the group.

`COUNT(condition) / COUNT(*) * 100` returns the ratio of the above in percent.

Comment: (Be careful when dividing integer quantites... you may get 1000/1000000 = 0)

Comment: @joanolo can you give an example where Oracle doesn't promote to `number` when you divide: http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=96201684aa58c64c1a66112353256d5a

Comment: @JackDouglas: not really for Oracle [didn't really pay enough attention to the tag]; but in SQL in general (or if you ever move from one DB to another) it's safer to cast, or just rewrite starting with a numeric (or float): `100.0* COUNT(condition)  / COUNT(*)`

Comment: Another way: `avg(case when condition is null then 0 else 1 end)`